# Nested while loop is not working as expected

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, nested

I'm having a problem in php. I tried to show all data and then put them in a nested loop. but the second loop only returns nulls. I don't know what I did wrong.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000); 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","XXX","YahooFin");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"show tables from yahooFin where not tables_in_yahooFin = 'nasdaqCompanyList' and not tables_in_yahooFin = 'companylist'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from ".$row['Tables_in_yahoofin']." where entry_date = '2013-06-03'order by entry_date asc limit 1");
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2));  //<== This line gives me null
    {
        var_dump( $row2);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
var_dump($row);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You're assuming that your queries are working; add some debugging in there, and find out what's going on. What does `mysqli_error($con)` print out?

Comment: Maybe upper/lower case missmatch in `tables_in_yahooFin`? In second loop it is `Tables_in_yahooFin`. BTW, if you limit your results to `1`, what for the second loop?

Answer (score 3):

There is an extra `;` semicolon which shouldn't be there after your loop

```
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2));  //<== This line gives me null
                                              //^ remove this one
```

Also You probably have a typo `tables_in_yahooFin` is used in first query while `Tables_in_yahoofin` is used in second.

Comment: oh dear, you're correct. this teach my not to code under the influence  of cough medicine. thanks a lot!

Comment: @fredi you are welcome, don't forget to accept answer to help people in the future with similar problems. To accept you just need to click on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score